# Model on md-dialog not refreshing automatically in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am bit new to angular I am using two autocomplete in md-dialog in which data of second autocomplete changes according to first autocpmlete fr eg. first autocomplete is state and second is cities so second will change according to first. But In my case model is array of cities is changing but it is not reflecting in front end PLEASE HELP
Thanks...

my automplete inside md-dialog
 `

```
 <md-autocomplete flex="15"style="margin: 10px 10px;height:40px;border-bottom:solid 1px grey;"
 md-search-text="materialName"
          md-selected-item-change="materialChanged(material)"
          md-items="material in MaterialsforSales | filter:material.materialName"
          md-item-text="material.materialName"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Select Material"
          md-autofocus>
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="material.materialName" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{material.materialName}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <div ng-messages="AddProductionOrderForm.materialName.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Material is required.</div>
          </div>
      </md-autocomplete>
```

`

and controllers look like this

```
$scope.salePlanChanged = function(salePlan){
        $scope.salePlan = salePlan;
        $scope.MaterialsforSales =[];
        $scope.materialsBySaleId();
    }
    $scope.materialsBySaleId=function(){
        $http
        .get('/link that get materials by id/'+$scope.salePlan.salePlanNo)
        .then(function(response) {
            debugger;
            if(response.data==""){
                console.log($scope.MaterialsforSales);
                $scope.NoData=true;   
                $scope.isActivated=false
            }
            else{
                $scope.MaterialsforSales = response.data;
                $scope.showData=true;
                $scope.isActivated=false;               
            }           
        }); 
    }
```

**$scope.MaterialsforSales** is chnging but not reflecting in front end

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working as expected?

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to the question?